# Individual Assignment in Google Classroom API

Tags: google-classroom

I am integrating google classroom with python, For creating classwork on course below code is working fine. reference : https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-coursework

```
courseWork = {  
  'title': 'sample assignment',  
  'description': 'Read the article about ant colonies and complete the quiz.',  
  'materials': [  
     {'link': { 'url': 'http://example.com/ant-colonies' }}
],  
  'workType': 'ASSIGNMENT',  
  'state': 'PUBLISHED',  
}  
courseWork = service.courses().courseWork().create(  
    courseId='<course ID or alias>', body=courseWork).execute()  
print('Assignment created with ID {0}'.format(courseWork.get('id')))
```

**Here I want to create an assignment on few students of class not all. How can I do this?**

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`modifyAssignees`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/modifyAssignees) method. Here you need to set [`assigneeMode`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/AssigneeMode) to `INDIVIDUAL_STUDENTS`. And provide specific student ID-s to [`IndividualStudentsOptions`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/IndividualStudentsOptions) field.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, I can't see any documentation regarding your use case. Based from your [reference](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-coursework#create_assignments) it seems that it only provides creating assignments for a group, not for an individual student. However, UI Google Classroom has functional for selecting students from a list.

You can file a [feature request](https://developers.google.com/classroom/support#missing_features) for this.